# How can I get Watson Conversation to request username/passwords from a chat and then use that to login to another system

Tags: security, ibm-cloud, chatbot, watson-assistant

I'm planning to use a Watson Conversation to talk to users of my app. I want the Conversation to ask people to log in (to Salesforce) if they're not currently logged in - but I'm struggling to work out how to train Watson to look for usernames and passwords. Given the vast array of different possible username and password combinations it's going to be really hard to train Watson to know what to look for.

I'm using node-salesforce as the mechanism to login to salesforce if that matters, not the Watson Salesforce SDK.

How can I prompt a user to provide this information then get Watson to trigger the login on their behalf?

Answer (score 4):

Have you checked what information ends up in log files? You can specify that IBM is not using dialog data, but still, the password is transferred a couple times before your app has access to it. Who guarantees security? Is it your app design, would you blame IBM in case of security issues, would users accept that approach (I would not)?

If your app drives the dialog and has the UI, why not provide a link to a login page? I am not familiar with the Salesforce API, but many APIs allow token-based access and users can authorize apps to log in on their behalf. Before investigating the regex functionality in Watson Assistant and how to obtain the password, I would reconsider the app design.

Comment: Completely agree @data_henrik.  Asking users to provide their user name and password is usually considered an anti-pattern https://adactio.com/journal/1357/ and should only be used as a last resort.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any guide that's basic that shows how I might go about this. I've cloned a repo where the user interface is a Telegram app, and I'm struggling to work out how IBM Watson Conversation can be used to identify whether a user has logged in (presumably checking for a token and issuing a login link if none exists).